# Центрирование динамических блоков

Tags: javascript, html, css

Я пытаюсь решить эту проблему уже 2 месяца. Результатов 0. Пишу теперь суда.
Так, у нас есть некий `<div id="header">` который лежит сразу после body.
После него есть такой блок `<div id="cent-block">` . Интуитивно понятно, что header лежит в самом верху документа.

### **Наша цель: расположить cent-block ровно по середине экрана.**

---

Что я для этого сделал:

```
var i = document.documentElement.clientWidth;
element  = document.getElementById("header");
var i2 = element.offsetHeight;
element = document.getElementById("cent-block");
var i3 = element.offsetHeight;
```

А-ля вычеслил высоту каждого из блока, включая высоту всего документа.
Затем из высоты всего документа вычитаю высоту второго блока, (т.е шапки)

```
 i = i - i2;
```

Потом вычитаю из полученного высоту центрального блока.

```
i = i - i3;
```

И в конце концов разделил на две равные части.

```
 i = i/2
```

Посе чего зафиксировал полученный результат.

```
document.getElementById("cent-block").style.marginTop = i+"px";
```

Которого так и не оказалось. Очень прошу помочь. Всем спасибо за внимание.

Comment: По-моему, `clientWidth` нужно заменить на `clientHeight`. А вообще, отчего бы не воспользоваться CSS?

Comment: CSS? А у меня же нет точных размеров. Как я буду вычислять то, что мне требуется? Спасибо, работает.

Comment: Я бы использовал [flexbox](https://philipwalton.github.io/solved-by-flexbox/demos/vertical-centering/) с его `align-items` и `justify-content`, добавив fallback для старых браузеров, чтобы у них блок, скажем, располагался со смещением на 200 пикселей сверху. Хотя, конечно, можно вместо этого по-старинке обернуть блок в таблицу с одной ячейкой и `vertical-align:middle`.

Comment: @LiteSupport резина, на то и резина, чтобы тянутся от размеров экрана автоматически. Смотрите в сторону `flex`